# Sum the value of 2 inputs made in laravel 8 for each product with jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a problem with my project, I have 2 inputs that I want to add dynamically to show the value in an alert when pressing the button, each product has 2 inputs, but I can't make it work with all of them, it only adds the first 2 inputs from the first products, I hope can you help me:

Code on blade

```
@foreach($productsArray['data'] as $product)
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="stock-modal" class="col-form-label">Precio Base:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="stockPriceprueba" value="{{ $product['precioBase'] }}" disabled>
        </div>
        <div name="prueba" class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="stock-modal" class="col-form-label">Aumento sobre el precio base:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="prueba" type="number" class="form-control" name="priceModalprueba">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" name="button-addonprueba">Calcular Precio</button>
    @endforeach
```

jQuery code

```
$("button[name=button-addonprueba]").click(function () {
    valor1 = parseFloat($("input[name=priceModalprueba]").val());
    valor2 = parseFloat($("input[name=stockPriceprueba]").val());
    TotalSuma = valor1 + valor2;
    alert(TotalSuma);
});
```

Comment: Do you want sum of all products or just a single product for each button?

Comment: a single product

Comment: Hi, is this problem solved ?

Comment: hi, no, i need help with this part of code, i need this value on my jquery file {{ $product['precioBase'] }}

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each set in a container row (or any other class you want). Then when you click a button traverse up to that row using `closest()` then `find()` the inputs within that row.

Note you can't repeat element IDs in a  page. I used some common classes instead of names to make the selectors simpler

```js
$('.button-addonprueba').click(function(e) {
  const $row = $(this).closest('.row'),
    price = $row.find('input.price').prop('valueAsNumber') || 0,
    stock = $row.find('input.stock').prop('valueAsNumber') || 0,
    total = price + stock;

  console.log('Product Total =', total)

})
```

```css
.row {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- php loop to create html-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="stock-modal" class="col-form-label">Precio Base:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control stock" name="stockPriceprueba" value="10" disabled>
  </div>
  <div name="prueba" class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="stock-modal" class="col-form-label">Aumento sobre el precio base:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control price" name="priceModalprueba" value="6">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary button-addonprueba" type="button">Calcular Precio</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- new row from php loop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="stock-modal" class="col-form-label">Precio Base:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control stock" name="stockPriceprueba" value="100" disabled>
  </div>
  <div name="prueba" class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="stock-modal" class="col-form-label">Aumento sobre el precio base:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control price" name="priceModalprueba" value="66">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary button-addonprueba" type="button">Calcular Precio</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this code work, but the value of my input is {{ $product['precioBase'] }} i need help with that

Comment: OK that is server side blade template code that can't be run in browser, only server side. That is why I hard coded some simple values just for this demo

Comment: Thank you, this demonstration helped me a lot, if you can help me with that value, I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You'd ideally need to introduce a counter in the code so you end up with name such as stockPriceprueba0, stockPriceprueba1 and then do that same loop in the jQuery section. You can do this with a standard php block in the blade template.

```
<?php i=0?>
@foreach($productsArray['data'] as $product)
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <label for="stock-modal" class="col-form-label">Precio Base:</label>
         <input type="number" class="form-control" name="stockPriceprueba{{$i}}" value="{{ $product['precioBase'] }}" disabled>
     </div>
     <div name="prueba" class="col-sm-6">
         <label for="stock-modal" class="col-form-label">Aumento sobre el precio base:</label>
         <div class="input-group">
             <input id="prueba" type="number" class="form-control" name="priceModalprueba{{$i}}">
         </div>
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" name="button-addonprueba">Calcular Precio</button>
 <?php $i++ ?>
 @endforeach
```

And similarly on the jQuery section you can:

```
$("button[name=button-addonprueba]").click(function () {
    TotalSuma = 0;
    @for($x=0; $x< count($productsArray); $x++)
    valor1 = parseFloat($("input[name=priceModalprueba{{$x}}]").val());
    valor2 = parseFloat($("input[name=stockPriceprueba{{$x}}]").val());
    TotalSuma += valor1 + valor2;
    @endfor
  
    alert(TotalSuma);
```

Comment: this code dont work, show an error, if you can help me please

Comment: You can't run a php loop in javascript code running in browser

Comment: @charlietfl This is in no way running a php loop in JavaScript. It is dynamically writing the JavaScript using a php loop in a blade file.

Comment: @charlieftl Not sure why you think it simply can't be done this way. [https://phpsandbox.io/n/shy-leaf-omk8-dkcaa](https://phpsandbox.io/n/shy-leaf-omk8-dkcaa) The php is just rendering the javascript, it's not mixing php and javascript in the browser. Just view the source. It does simply work just like this